# Synched Timer Across all Application instances

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Could anyone maybe lend some advice.

I need to create a Global Timer for every instance of my application

For a Time'd Sale of sorts, The use case Is that a Product will be on a Quick sale for 10 minutes then Disappear. Now there needs to be a timer but it would have to be synched across all application regardless of what time they open the application.

Now what i've done is used a webview with a Online Reoccurring timer. The issue with this is that I realised I'd have to clear the quick sale cart when the timer is up, So that people cant checkout products for the quick sale price when the sale is over. And with the webview I cant read that value to do that

So in Essence my Question is: What are my Alternative options/Option to get a Synchronised Timer That I can read the Value from To use for Functionality later on.

Another Solution I had was that, I could check on the OnAppearing() of the quick Cart if that Product still exists under the quick products And if not remove it form the list but, I'd like to stay away from webviews

Comment: Is it possible to let server check the sale time at checkout? So you don't have to handle each devices individually at checkout. Also you don't have to sync sale starter accurately.

Comment: Sadly no, I'm using a API for my Product interactions and orders ect, And the issue is this isn't a typical Ecommerce application its for a Market So people walk threw the market and purchase so they'd need all see the exact same time. And theyd actually need a visual timer running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store Timer end value in a database and get it everytime somebody enters your site to calculate time left, if the time is over then You can call your API method for orders to remove products of some ID from every not finished order.

Another way is to use the same process but with service and it's probably better way to do so. Every app could request the Timer end value from service and use it to calculate time left.

Comment: So what i've done is, I've made the application remove any Item thats not longer part of the Quick sale Category, What I'm going to try and do now is automate the Removal of the products on the Website side  when the timer's up so I think, Yeah i'll be using a Database value to correlate this

Comment: You could add an event on timer finished to call some method which would call your API. But this is possible only with service solution.